# Load .json files on Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Basically i want to convert a .json file, into a Lua table, i'm using this [tutorial](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/08/03/tutorial-exploring-json-usage-in-corona/) ( probably out of date ), but i'm getting the following error:

```
attempt to call global 'jsonFile' (a nil value)
```

**menu.lua**

```
local json = require ("json")
local tableJson = json.decode( jsonFile("teste.json") )
```

**teste.json**

```
{
    "name": "Jack (\"Bee\") Nimble", 
    "format": {
        "shape":       "rect", 
        "width":      1920, 
        "height":     1080, 
        "interlace":  false, 
        "framerate": 24
    }
}
```

I have looked for "jsonFile", on the official API reference, but there's nothing there, and i did not found any way to do this.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`json.decode` receives a string so you probably need to read the contents of the file.
Try this:

```
function jsonFile(file)
    local f,err = io.open(file, "r")
    if f==nil then
        return f,err
    else
        local content = f:read("*all")
        f:close()
        return content
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [json.decodeFile](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/json/decodeFile.html) function to decodes the contents of a file that is expected to contain JSON-encoded data.